# ¿Como poner viñetas en un PDF con FPDF?

Tags: php, array, fpdf

Me podrían ayudar a saber como puedo hacer una tabla con FPDF que en una celda o Multicelda contenga varias viñetas, como la que se muestra en la imagen.

[Tabla con Viñetas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14U9s.png)

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Comment: aqui tienes lo que buscas: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script56.php

Comment: eso ya lo logro pero quiero poner una lista de viñetas en una Columna  como se ve en la imagen que adjunte

Comment: en efecto en el segundo link tienes viñetas..

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex56.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Como se indica en la [documentación de FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script38.php), lo que buscas es un MultiCell with Bullet. Lo puedes añadir así:

```php
require('MultiCellBlt.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa para añadirlas podria ser que descargues el icono de la viñeta que quieres insertar en el pdf y las  trabajes como imagenes y las vas posicionando delante del texto.